# Compile time string generator based on templates

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-hana

I am developing a GUI based on mfc. One of the controls allows a markup languge (XAML) to render text and icons inside it, so I am doing an intensive use of it. The markup string is almost the same for all the controls (12 in a form), so I wondered if it would be an easy way to make a function to generate that string.

So the control are predefined and does not change during execution, I would like to generate those strings at compile time, as well as if they were directly typed and then compiled.

I am using `boost::hana` for it, but I am not able of using string literals in a template by any of the ways I have tried. I know that there is not posible to directly use string literals in templates due to unknown memory allocation at compile time.

Besides the classical tricks of using `extern` or `static` allocation in a struct, what I dislike due to adding syntax complexity, is there any way in C++17 (or below, but NOT c++20 please) to allow this?

Note- An extra should be to directly format the int (use 10 instead of "10") in the function not using a macro.

The code is next, and of course, it does NOT compile in its current form:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

constexpr auto markup1()
{
    return (BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(<Border Padding='4' BorderThickness='2' BorderBrush='#767676' Background='#e4ecf7'>
            <StackPanel TextBlock.FontFamily='Tahoma'>
            <Border Margin='4' Padding='4' Background='#FF212C'><TextBlock HorizontalAlignment='Center' Foreground='#ffffff' FontSize='24' FontWeight='Bold'>)") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING("USERS") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(</TextBlock></Border>
            <TextBlock Padding='9, 6, 30, 7' FontWeight='Bold' TextWrapping='Wrap'>)") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING("User Management. Allows creation of administrators and users.") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(</TextBlock>
            <Border Height='1' Background='#9ebbdd'/>
            <Border Height='1' Background='White'/>
            <Image Source=')") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING("10") + 

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(' Margin='10' VerticalAlignment='Center'/>
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>)") ).c_str();
}

template <const char* header, const char* description, const char* image>
constexpr auto markup2()
{
    return (BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(<Border Padding='4' BorderThickness='2' BorderBrush='#767676' Background='#e4ecf7'>
            <StackPanel TextBlock.FontFamily='Tahoma'>
            <Border Margin='4' Padding='4' Background='#FF212C'><TextBlock HorizontalAlignment='Center' Foreground='#ffffff' FontSize='24' FontWeight='Bold'>)") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(header) +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(</TextBlock></Border>
            <TextBlock Padding='9, 6, 30, 7' FontWeight='Bold' TextWrapping='Wrap'>)") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(description) +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(</TextBlock>
            <Border Height='1' Background='#9ebbdd'/>
            <Border Height='1' Background='White'/>
            <Image Source=')") +

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(image) + 

        BOOST_HANA_STRING(R"(' Margin='10' VerticalAlignment='Center'/>
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>)") ).c_str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1 { markup1() };
    std::string str2 { markup2<"USERS", "User Management. Allows creation of administrators and users.", "10">() };
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (str1 == str2); 
}
```

A direct access to coliru is available: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a5bc326be33cb3e

Comment: I guess it can work without C++20 using array-references rather than pointers, but you can't pass string literals directly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42a06bb8a77f4a0b

Comment: @idjam Your solution looks fine to me. Do you want to upgrade it into an answer so people can vote for it?

Comment: How about `constexpr auto str2 = markup2(BOOST_HANA_STRING("USERS"), BOOST_HANA_STRING("User Manag..", BOOST_HANA_STRING("10"));`?

Comment: @Pablo: Like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/338e95b1c1efcfc6).

Comment: @Jarod42 So cool!!! Very nice solution, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not legal to pass string literals directly as template arguments, ever; however, one may bind the string literal to a `constexpr` array and pass that (by reference) instead:

```
template<auto const& header, auto const& description, auto const& image>
constexpr auto markup2() { ... }

int main() {
    static constexpr char const h2[] = "USERS";
    static constexpr char const d2[] = "User Management. Allows creation of administrators and users.";
    static constexpr char const i2[] = "10";

    std::string_view const str1{ markup1() },
                           str2{ markup2<h2, d2, i2>() };
    return str1 == str2; 
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Pxr48xsj)**</kbd>

Naturally, C++20 has multiple options for making this a bit prettier, after writing some boilerplate up front.

Answer (score 1):

You might take your `HANA_STRING` as "regular" (need to be template) arguments:

```
template <typename Header, typename Description, typename Image>
constexpr auto markup2(Header header, Description description, Image image)
{
    return (BOOST_HANA_STRING(
R"(<Border Padding='4' BorderThickness='2' BorderBrush='#767676' Background='#e4ecf7'>
<StackPanel TextBlock.FontFamily='Tahoma'>
<Border Margin='4' Padding='4' Background='#FF212C'>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment='Center' Foreground='#ffffff' FontSize='24' FontWeight='Bold'>)")

    + header
    + BOOST_HANA_STRING(
R"(</TextBlock></Border>
<TextBlock Padding='9, 6, 30, 7' FontWeight='Bold' TextWrapping='Wrap'>)")

    + description
    + BOOST_HANA_STRING(
R"(</TextBlock>
<Border Height='1' Background='#9ebbdd'/>
<Border Height='1' Background='White'/>
<Image Source=')")

    + image

    + BOOST_HANA_STRING(
R"(' Margin='10' VerticalAlignment='Center'/>
</StackPanel>
</Border>)") ).c_str();
}
```

with call similar to

```
std::string str2 { markup2(
    BOOST_HANA_STRING("USERS"),
    BOOST_HANA_STRING("User Management. Allows creation of administrators and users."),
    BOOST_HANA_STRING("10")) };
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/338e95b1c1efcfc6)