# compile-time variable-length objects based on string

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr

### Related SO questions:

- [variable size struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429767/how-can-i-have-a-compile-time-const-object-configured-with-a-chunk-of-data-of-va)
- [string-based generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907778/compile-time-string-generator-based-on-templates)

Sadly neither one (or other similar ones) provide the solution I'm looking for.

### Background

USB descriptors are (generally) byte-array structures. A "string descriptor" is defined as an array of bytes, that begins with a standard "header" of 2 bytes, followed by a string of UNICODE (16-bit) characters.

For example a USB string descriptor of value "AB" would have the following sequence of bytes:

```
0x06 0x03 0x41 0x00 0x42 0x00
```

where `0x06` is the total size of the descriptor (including the header), `0x03` is its "type" (defined by the standard)

### Current (unsatisfactory) approach:

```
// other types omitted for clarity
enum UsbDescriptorType: uint8_t { USB_DESCR_STRING = 0x03 };

struct UsbDescrStd {
    uint8_t bLength;
    UsbDescriptorType bDescriptorType;
};

template<size_t N>
struct UsbDescrString final: UsbDescrStd {
    char str[N * 2];

    constexpr UsbDescrString(const char s[N]) noexcept
        : UsbDescrStd{sizeof(*this), UsbDescriptorType::USB_DESCR_STRING}
        , str {}
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            str[i * 2] = s[i];
    }
};
```

Below are the examples of its usage and short comments on why they are "not good enough" for me:

```
// requires size information
constexpr UsbDescrString<9> uds9{"Descr str"};

// string duplication
constexpr UsbDescrString<sizeof("Descr str")-1> udsa{"Descr str"};

// requires an explicit string storage
constexpr auto UsbDescrStrTxt{"Descr str"};
constexpr UsbDescrString<sizeof(UsbDescrStrTxt)-1> udsa2{UsbDescrStrTxt};

// ugly use of a macro
#define MAKE_UDS(name, s) UsbDescrString<sizeof(s)-1> name{s}
constexpr MAKE_UDS(udsm, "Descr str");
```

"String argument to template" is explicitly prohibited as of C++20, cutting that solution off as well.

### What I'm trying to achieve

Ideally I'd love to be able to write code like the following:

```
constexpr UsbDescrString uds{"Descr str"}; // or a similar "terse" approach
```

It is simple, terse, error-resistant, and to the point. And I need help writing my `UsbDescrString` in a way that allows me to create compile-time objects without unnecessary code bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to `UsbDescrString` should be enough

```
template<size_t N>
struct UsbDescrString final: UsbDescrStd {
    char str[N * 2];

    constexpr UsbDescrString(const char (&s)[N+1]) noexcept
        : UsbDescrStd{sizeof(*this), UsbDescriptorType::USB_DESCR_STRING}
        , str {}
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            str[i * 2] = s[i];
    }
};

template<size_t N>
UsbDescrString(const char (&)[N]) -> UsbDescrString<N-1>;
```

Note that in order to prevent array to pointer decay, `const char (&)` needs to be used as the constructor parameter.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z8M4cPzan)

> "String argument to template" is explicitly prohibited as of C++20,
> cutting that solution off as well.

However, thanks to [P0732](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf), with the help of some helper classes such as `basic_fixed_string`, now in C++20 you can

```
template<fixed_string>
struct UsbDescrString final: UsbDescrStd;

constexpr UsbDescrString<"Descr str"> uds9;
```

Comment: Is std::basic_fixed_string available in c++20 ?? I could not find any info about it in cppreference

Comment: @nhatnq `std::basic_fixed_string` was not introduced in C++20, but it can be [easily implemented](https://godbolt.org/z/vjGbhnfx3).